# How to filter a datagrid when it's itemsource if the default view of a datatable

Tags: wpf, datagrid, filter, datatable

I am trying to filter a datagrid to show only the rows that contain the search term. The data from a database is loaded to the datatable first and then the itemSource of the datagrid is set as the datatable. All the filter method I found online requires to change the data to a I CollectionView. I used the current code

```
    List<DataRow> list = dataTable.AsEnumerable().ToList();                               
    ICollectionView view = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(list);
    dataGrid.ItemsSource = view;                
    if (view != null)                
    {                    
         view.Filter = delegate(object o)                   
         {
               var row = o as DataRow;
               for (int j = 0; j < dataTable.Columns.Count; j++)                     
               {
                    string data = row.ItemArray[j].ToString();                            
                    if (data != null)                            
                    {                               
                        if (data.Contains(SearchBox.Text))                                   
                             return true;                           
                    }                        
                }                        
             return false;                   
         };

                dataGrid.ItemsSource = view;
```

The result is that, if the matched rows are of number two, I will get two rows left but of blank value. All the data in the rows can not show. So the data is in the IcollectionView, but it just doesn't show up. Any ideas? I really really appreciate. Just to clarify,Before I add this filter function, I just use

```
          dataGrid.ItemSource = dataTable.DefaultView;
```

Everything works fine. Thank you.

Comment: instead of ICollection view you could also use the RowFilter from the DataTable.DefaultView.

Comment: I tried to use RowFilter. But my goal is to filter all the rows that contains my search term. Since some of my columns' types are not text, when I try to use query, error happens.